# For measures $P,Q $ on $R$, if $Q(A) = P(A+x)$ and $|x| < \epsilon$ , then $\pi(P,Q) < \epsilon$ where $\pi$ is the Prohorov metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

For measures on the line, show that if $Q(A) = P(A+x)$ and $|x| < \epsilon$ , then $\pi(P,Q) < \epsilon$.

Here $\pi$ is the Prohorov distance, i.e. the infimum of those positive $\epsilon$ for which the two inequalities 
$$PA \le QA^\epsilon + \epsilon, \; QA \le PA^\epsilon + \epsilon$$ holds for all Borel sets $A$.

So essentially we need to show that for any $r<\epsilon$, we have either $PA \le QA^r + r$ or $QA \le PA^r + r$, for all Borel sets $A$, which gives $\pi(P,Q) \le r < \epsilon$. However, I don't know how to compare $P(A^r + x)$ with $P(A)$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Just curious, what is $A^r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $A+x \subset A^{\epsilon}$ and $A \subset A^{\epsilon} +x$ whenever $|x|<\epsilon$. Hence we get $Q(A)=P(A+x) \leq P(A^{\epsilon})<P(A^{\epsilon})+\epsilon$ and, similarly, $P(A) \leq P(A^{\epsilon}+x)=Q(A^{\epsilon})<Q(A^{\epsilon})+\epsilon$.